# Cocos2D iPhone - will this save memory?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

When you create a sprite on cocos using a texture you allocate memory.

Something like:

```
CCTexture2D *textureProxy = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:image];
CCSprite *proxy1 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:textureProxy];
```

My question is: suppose I want several sprites using the same texture and I do

```
CCSprite *proxy1 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:textureProxy];
CCSprite *proxy2 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:textureProxy];
CCSprite *proxy3 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:textureProxy];
CCSprite *proxy4 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:textureProxy];
CCSprite *proxy5 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:textureProxy];
```

Will I use 5 times more memory? (or in other words, will the texture be duplicated to each proxy or is the sprite just a "empty box" that references the original texture?

If the later is the answer, then the memory usage for similar sprites are not that huge, right?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprites keep only references to `textureProxy`. Even if you create each sprite with `spriteWithFile:`, file names are cached in `CCTextureCache`.

Answer (score 1):

In cocos Different memories are allocated for texture and variables. So if u keep on creating just variables using same texture won't add up texture memory multiple times. And CCSprite objects are autoreleased objects.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was afraid I was using too much memory. :D